# PowerShell - Using Exchange Server 2016 REST API to get Calendar Events

Tags: rest, powershell, exchange-server

I have a script calendar items of a resource mailbox using REST API  - but get this error in Exchange Server 2016 - not sure what the problem is - my account has applicationimpersonation role.

Error message :

```
 Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:2 char:28
+ ...              $events = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $creds
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

script:

```
$Username = 'Contoso\administrator'
$Password = 'xxxxxxx'
$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecureString 
$mtgroom = @("meeting@contoso.com") 
$strCurrentTimeZone = (Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName
$TZ = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($strCurrentTimeZone)
$start = (get-date).ToShortDateString()
$end = (get-date).ToShortDateString()
$uri = "https://mail.contoso.com/api/v2.0/users/$mtgroom/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=$($start)T08:00:00&endDateTime=$($end)T19:30:00"
 $events = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $creds
```

Comment: I think you'd better use the [Sortable DateTime Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier). `(Get-Date).ToString("s")` which returns the current date as `2019-03-13T14:16:29`

Comment: I figured it out it now I have another issue I have updated my question

Comment: So you _had_ a date issue and that is gone now and you have a different one? If that is you we should close this question and open another one instead of changing the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is likely because of how your date time strings are formed. In my environment I get "3/13/2019" from using `(get-date).ToShortDateString()`. That could contribute to a malformed URL. I could be wrong depending on your localization settings.

Do you get better results from `get-date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"` for your start and end dates?

---

The example from [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#get-a-calendar-view) also uses hyphenated dates

> ```
> GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2014-10-01T01:00:00&endDateTime=2014-10-31T23:00:00&$select=Subject
> ```

Comment: Ok like you said I have reformatted date time strings. its works but I still have issue. I have updated my question.